# Expected value of $F(x)$.

Tags: probability, expectation

$$F(X)=\frac{99}{1-X}\quad\text{and}\quad X\equiv Uniform[0,1]$$
What is the expected value of above distribution. I tried calculating but I find the expected value integral doesn't converge.

Is my calculation correct? 
What is the implication of expected value of integral not converging? Is the variance also not convergent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, it does not converge:
$$
\mathbb{E}[F(X)] = \int_0^1 F(x)dx = \int_0^1 \frac{99}{1-x}dx = +\infty
$$

This is alright, and can happen: not every random variable has a finite expectation! (For instance, look at the famous [Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution).)

What this means is exactly that: the expectation of the random variable $F(X)$ is infinite. *(It is, at least, defined, since $F(X)\geq 0$: it just is infinite. The expectation of a Cauchy r.v. is not even defined, since a Cauchy r.v. takes both negative and positive values.)*

A consequence? Indeed, then it does not have a variance either. This is because "having a variance implies having an expectation" (or, in fancier terms, $L_1$-integrable implies $L_2$-integrable for random variables). To show why, you can e.g. use Cauchy--Schwarz:
$$
0 \leq \mathbb{E}[\lvert Y\rvert ] = \mathbb{E}[\lvert Y\rvert\cdot 1] \leq \sqrt{\mathbb{E}[Y^2]\mathbb{E}[1]} = \sqrt{\mathbb{E}[Y^2]}
$$
Thus, if $\mathbb{E}[Y^2] <\infty$, then $\mathbb{E}[\lvert Y\rvert ]<\infty$ as well, meaning that $Y$ is integrable (has a finite expectation).

Comment: Could you add what it would mean in terms prediction and such? For example repeated samples from a probability distribution would give a gaussian with mean(of original distribution) and variance(depending on number of trials and variance of original distribution). How would such a distribution behave in this case?

Comment: No law of large numbers, for instance. Read up on the Cauchy distribution on Wikipedia, this sort of things is discussed.

Comment: alright got it. Would say this is a good distribution for setting gambling odds?

Comment: Depends whether you're the casino or the players. I would say it's highly unpredictable, but that the fact that the expectation of the gains is infinite isnot necessarily a good thing if you're the house.

Comment: Thanks a lot this will clear up a lot of things for me.

Comment: You're welcome.